# About minimal polynomial in a general field

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

Let $\alpha$ be an algebraic element over a field $K$. If $f(x) = x^n -a, g(x)=x^m -a$ are irreducible polynomials in $K[x]$ such that $f(\alpha^m) = g(\alpha^n) =0$ and $n,m$ are coprime; I'm asked to find the degree of the extension $K(\alpha) : K$ and the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ in $K$.

I don't really know how to work on the problem since, from my point of view, the solution itself should depend on the field $K$ and the element $a\in K$ (unless the condition of irreducibility for both $f,g$ manages these scenarios). I would really appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: By the way, you mean "algebraic *over* a field $K$", not "in". If it is *in* $K$, the $K(\alpha)=K$ from the get-go.

Comment: Hint: You know $[K(\alpha^m):K]$ and $[K(\alpha^n):K]$, right? Try and show that $K(\alpha)=K(\alpha^m,\alpha^n)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you so much! It follows from a Bezout identity between $n,m$ as coprime numbers jeje

Comment: Indeed! Well done. Please consider posting a more detailed argument as an answer. That way you can get more feedback (and a few rep points).

Answer (score 1):

Note that $K(\alpha^m, \alpha^n)$ contains both $K(\alpha^m)$ and $K(\alpha^n)$,
so $[K(\alpha^m,\alpha^n):K]\ge mn$ because $\gcd(m,n)=1$.
But $[K(\alpha^m,\alpha^n):K]$ is also bounded above by $[K(\alpha^m):K][K(\alpha^n):K]=mn$,
so $[K(\alpha^m,\alpha^n):K]=mn$.

Now, since $\gcd(m,n)=1$, there are $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $pm+qn=1$.
Then $\alpha=(\alpha^m)^p (\alpha^n)^q\in K(\alpha^m,\alpha^n)$.
This shows that $K(\alpha)=K(\alpha^m,\alpha^n)$,
so $[K(\alpha):K]=mn$.
The minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$ is then $x^{mn}-a$
because it is a polynomial of degree $[K(\alpha):K]$ that vanishes $\alpha$.